# How to write Gdb batch script for a multi core environment?

Tags: c, debugging, batch-file, gdb

Is it possible to run four different gdb sessions in batch mode or a single script?

For example:

1. I have 4 different processor cores, fepu, mpu, sbmu and bepu. I go into the respective folders and do:

   ```
   ../scripts/rungdb.sh logs
   ```

The shell script reads the folder name and picks up the corresponding elf file to load and also runs gdb session for that particular core.

2. Then I do 'Continue' one by one for all the four processors.
3. I halt mpu by doing 'Ctrl C' in mpu-gdb and
4. Set an mpu register Set `*0x44880810 = 1`
5. Do 'C' to continue mpu core running again

Is it possible to automate all these steps in a single batch script ? If yes, then it will help me to include the script in my Python automation framework.

Comment: It's possible. Describe a bit more about how you're starting the component that acts as the `gdbserver`  (Are you using `openocd`, `JLinkGDBServer`?) and how you're connecting `gdb` to it (Are you `target extended-remote` or `target remote` in `mpu-gdb`? Which TCP ports are you using?)

Comment: Scottt, I am using Xtensa OCD Daemon (Copyrighted by Tensilica) to connect the mpu-gdb (which is the remote target CPU) to gdb (running on Unix server). Similar to mpu, there are 3 more targets as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: I'm guessing {fepu,mpu,sbmu,bepu}-gdb each uses a different transport channel, likely a different TCP port, to connect to one Xtensa OCD process. If you can tell me which TCP port each is using, I can present you a solution that'd require less adaptation to your environment and I don't have to come up and explain an artificial setup myself ;) Is `mpu-gdb` a shell script that calls `xt-gdb` with a `-x SOME-SCRIPT` argument?

Comment: Scottt, I am in a different time zone, so replying you late....yes you are correct, each gdb uses a different transport channel to connect to one Xtensa OCD process. When I start the Xtensa OCD Daemon on a Windows PC with a ip address say 135.20.2.0.160, a channel opens for FEPU:  135.20.2.0.160:20000 for MPU: 135.20.2.0.160:20001, for SBMU: 135.20.2.0.160:20002 and for BEPU: 135.20.2.0.160: 20003.

Comment: Yes, all the cpu core-gdb are shell scripts which I need to invoke or run from the corresponding CPU folder (the script parses the folders name to load that particular processors elf file which was generated in the build process and residing in the corresponding CPU directory (like fepu/fepu.elf and so on)

Comment: In the script file GDB is invoked like this: GDB="$XTENSA_TOOLS_ROOT/bin/xt-gdb --xtensa-system=$XTENSA_SYSTEM --xtensa-core=$XTENSA_CORE_NAME \
122  --xtensa-params="

Comment: And the settings are like this: $GDB $ELF --nx --nw \
--ex="set pagination off"  \
--ex="set \$Autotest_Watchpoints=$Watchpoints"  \
--ex="set \$Autotest_Debug=$Debug"  \
--ex="set logging file $LOGFILE" \
--ex="set logging on" \
--ex="source $SCRIPT_FOLDER/xt-gdb.scr.custom" \
--ex="source $SCRIPT_FOLDER/autotest/FC_GdbAutotestEngine.scr" \
--ex="connectBepu" \
--ex="$clearRom" \
--ex="$loadgcu" \
--ex="$InitNewFifoConfig" \
--ex="$runCpu" \
--ex="load $ELF" \
--ex="PrintRunStates" \
--ex="echo $ELF\n"